# loadTestRunner - how to set parameters using groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui, load-testing

I'd like to run load tests in soap using groovy script (as test step or Setup Script - which is better?) I can already set threads and startDelay but I don't know how to set strategy and specific options for each strategy (for example Burst Delay or Burst Duration).

I'm stuck with below code:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.loadtest.*
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.loadtest.strategy.*
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.support.*

def loadTest = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("Load").getTestCaseByName("testCase").getLoadTestByName("loadTestSelect")
def loadTestRunner = new WsdlLoadTestRunner(loadTest)

loadTestRunner.loadTest.setThreadCount(30)
loadTestRunner.loadTest.setStartDelay(2)
loadTestRunner.loadTest.setLoadStrategy("Simple")

loadTestRunner.start(true)
loadTestRunner.waitUntilFinished()
```

setThreadCount and setStartDelay works properly, but setLoadStrategy doesn't. I have an error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.loadtest.WsdlLoadTest.setLoadStrategy() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [Simple] Possible solutions: setLoadStrategy(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.loadtest.strategy.LoadStrategy), getLoadStrategy() error

I tried also find something (any expamples) in documentation - but I didn't.

I want to set these options:

[screenshot from soapUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm85F.png)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by...me :)

```
    def loadTest = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("Load").getTestCaseByName(testCaseSelect).getLoadTestByName(loadTestSelect)

//strategy params
def configSimple = """<xml-fragment>
<testDelay>${testDelay}</testDelay>
<randomFactor>${randomFactor}</randomFactor>
</xml-fragment>
"""
def configBurst = """<xml-fragment>
<burstDelay>${burstDelay}</burstDelay>
<burstDuration>${burstDuration}</burstDuration>
</xml-fragment>
"""
def configThread = """<xml-fragment>
<startThreadCount>${startThreadCount}</startThreadCount>
<endThreadCount>${endThreadCount}</endThreadCount>
</xml-fragment>
"""
def configVariance = """<xml-fragment>
<interval>${interval}</interval>
<variance>${variance}</variance>
</xml-fragment>
"""

switch (strategySelect) {
    case "Simple":
        xmlConfig = XmlObject.Factory.parse(configSimple)
        strategy = new SimpleLoadStrategy(xmlConfig, loadTest)
        break
    case "Burst":
        xmlConfig = XmlObject.Factory.parse(configBurst)
        strategy = new BurstLoadStrategy(xmlConfig, loadTest)
        break
    case "Thread":
        xmlConfig = XmlObject.Factory.parse(configThread)
        strategy = new ThreadCountChangeLoadStrategy(xmlConfig, loadTest)
        break
    case "Variance":
        xmlConfig = XmlObject.Factory.parse(configVariance)
        strategy = new VarianceLoadStrategy(xmlConfig, loadTest)
        break
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Niepoprawna wartość parametru strategySelect: ${strategySelect}")
}

loadTest.setLoadStrategy(strategy)
loadTest.setThreadCount(threads)
loadTest.setLimitType(LoadTestLimitTypesConfig.Enum.forString(limitType))
loadTest.setTestLimit(testLimit)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks marecki !**

I had a little issue with the construtor 'threadCountLoadStrategy' as you can see below (Solution : ***'.getXmlObject()'***) :

[image]

---

Here is a simple Groovy Script that add a load test to all cases in you project :
(of course you can reduce the scope)

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.loadtest.*
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.loadtest.strategy.*


def project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project

// Define the load test properties
def loadTestName = "LoadTest - Thread Strategy"
def threadCount = 50
def startThreadCount = 10
def endThreadCount = 50

project.getTestSuiteList().each { testSuite ->
    testSuite.getTestCaseList().each { testCase ->
        if (testCase instanceof WsdlTestCase) {
            def loadTest = testCase.getLoadTestByName(loadTestName)
            if (loadTest == null) {
                loadTest = testCase.addNewLoadTest(loadTestName)
            }

            def configThread = """<xml-fragment>
            <startThreadCount>${startThreadCount}</startThreadCount>
            <endThreadCount>${endThreadCount}</endThreadCount>
            </xml-fragment>"""
            
            def xmlHolder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(configThread)
            def strategy = new ThreadCountChangeLoadStrategy(xmlHolder.getXmlObject(), loadTest)
          
            loadTest.setLoadStrategy(strategy) // Set the strategy to Burst
            loadTest.setThreadCount(threadCount)
        }
    }
}

log.info("Load test with name $loadTestName has been added to all test cases in the project.")
```

*You can find all xml / function you need into the post of **@marecki***

: Becareful about BURST strategy you must set the value as follow to obtain 10

- def burstDelay = 10000
- def burstDuration = 10000
- def interval = 10000

Answer (score -1):

Based on the provided code snippet, it seems like you're trying to set the load strategy for a SoapUI load test. However, the error suggests that there is no method named `setLoadStrategy` available for `WsdlLoadTest`.

To set the load strategy for a SoapUI load test, you should use the `setStrategy` method instead. Here's an updated code snippet with the corrected method:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.loadtest.*
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.loadtest.strategy.*
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.support.*

def loadTest = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project
    .getTestSuiteByName("Load")
    .getTestCaseByName("testCase")
    .getLoadTestByName("loadTestSelect")

def loadTestRunner = new WsdlLoadTestRunner(loadTest)
loadTestRunner.loadTest.setThreadCount(30)
loadTestRunner.loadTest.setStartDelay(2)
loadTestRunner.loadTest.setStrategy(new SimpleLoadStrategy())
loadTestRunner.start(true)
loadTestRunner.waitUntilFinished()
```

In the updated code, `setStrategy` is used instead of `setLoadStrategy`. Additionally, the load strategy `SimpleLoadStrategy` is passed as an argument to the `setStrategy` method. You can adjust the load strategy according to your requirements, using one of the available load strategy classes provided by SoapUI.

Make sure you have imported the necessary classes for the load strategy and adjust the code as per your specific load testing needs.

Comment: I got similar suggestion from chatGpt - doesn't work :)